# Convert NSString to NSInteger?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsinteger

I want to convert `string` `data` to `NSInteger`.

Comment: If you google it you can easily get the answer in the first hit itself

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: At what point do abandoned questions like this get "auctioned" off for the community to buy with reputation points.... hmmm :-)

Comment: @KingOfBliss I googled it and my first hit was this post :)

Comment: @StephanCelis Before this, it was some other post. Now this ranked up based on most number of views :)

Answer (score 146):

If the string is a human readable representation of a number, you can do this:

```
NSInteger myInt = [myString intValue];
```

Comment: I believe the right side of the expression should be [myString integerValue], no?

Comment: `[myString intValue]` is a dark side ahaha

Comment: intValue returns an int, integerValue return an NSInteger. int is always an int type, but NSInteger changes types for the compiled device. There's more on that, but it's recommended to use NSInteger where ever possible.

Comment: I'm disappointed. If you do something like `[@"Test" integerValue]` it will return `0` because `Test` is not a number. This is an unsafe way to do this.

Answer (score 78):

`[myString intValue]` returns a cType "int"

`[myString integerValue]` returns a `NSInteger`.

In most cases I do find these simple functions by looking at apples class references, quickest way to get there is click [option] button and double-click on the class declarations (in this case NSString ).

Comment: simple and util tip. :)

Answer (score 25):

I've found this to be the proper answer.

```
NSInteger myInt = [someString integerValue];
```

Answer (score 9):

```
NSNumber *tempVal2=[[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] numberFromString:@"your text here"];
```

> returns NULL if string or returns NSNumber

```
NSInteger intValue=[tempVal2 integerValue];
```

> returns integer of NSNumber

Answer (score 2):

this is safer than integerValue:

```
-(NSInteger)integerFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber *numberObj = [formatter numberFromString:string];
    return [numberObj integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int myInt = [myString intValue];
NSLog(@"Display Int Value:%i",myInt);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theinteger];
```

Comment: He asked for the reverse of this.