# How to convert NSString to NSInteger in iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

```
NSString * addString=[arrayyyy componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"add string is: %@",addString);// result is: 45,1
```

Now I want to convert above string into integer.

I have tried this:

```
NSInteger myInt=[addString intValue]; 
//NSLog(@"myInt is: %d",myInt);// result is: 45
```

Comment: well, if the result is 45, its converted to int. [addString intValue] convert to int and [addString integerValue] convert to NSInteger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791470/convert-nsstring-to-nsinteger

Comment: @user993223 What do you mean by "Convert string into integer"?  What is the result that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you expected 45.1 then there are two things wrong :

1. `45.1` is not an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).  You would have to use `floatValue` to read the value.
2. `45,1` (notice the comma) is not a valid float number.  While `45,1` is valid in some locale (i.e. in french its `1 000,25` instead of `1,000.25`) you would have to convert the string with an [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) before reading the `floatValue`.

.

```
// Can't compile and verify this right now, so please bear with me.
NSString *str = @"45,1";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease]; // lets say French from France
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
float value = [[formatter numberFromString:str] floatValue];   // value = 45.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but  i want same result as an integer format, like 45,1, Please help me

Comment: `45.1` or `45,1` are **decimal** values. It's impossible to store them into an **integer**. Integers are whole values. The only way to put a decimal value into an integer is by rounding the value : it will result into `45`.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the question a lot, I think I may understand what you want.

The starting point seems to be:

```
NSLog(@"add string is: %@",addString);// result is: 45,1
```

And the current ending point is:

```
NSLog(@"myInt is: %d",myInt);// result is: 45
```

But it seems that you still want to print out 45,1

My guess on this is that you have an array of 2 strings [@"45",@"1"] called `arrayyyy` and you want to print out both values as integers.  If this is so then what I think you want  is:

```
NSInteger myInt1 = [[arrayyyy objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSInteger myInt2 = [[arrayyyy objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
NSLog(@"add string is: %d,%d",myInt1,myInt2);
```

**Note** This will crash horribly with an NSRangeException if there are not at least two strings in the array.  So at the very least you should do:

```
NSInteger myInt1 = -1;
NSInteger myInt2 = -1;
if ([arrayyyy length] >0) myInt1 = [[arrayyyy objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
if ([arrayyyy length] >1) myInt2 = [[arrayyyy objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
NSLog(@"add string is: %d,%d",myInt1,myInt2);
```

But even this is bad as it assumes that the guard value of `-1` will not be present in the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `NSExpression` which works with mathematical symbols too (i.e. `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`):

```
NSNumber *numberValue = [[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:inputString] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];

// do something with numberValue
```