# Why do I get this error when I try to pass a parameter in NSURL in iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl

This is what I have in a public method - (IBAction)methodName

```
NSString *quoteNumber = [[self textBox] text];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%d", quoteNumber];
```

The error I get is:

> Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initWithString` method can only accept a normal NSString, you are passing it a formatted NSString, Take a look at this code:

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%d", quotedNumber]];
```

That might be a bit confusing, you can break it up as follows:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%d", quotedNumber];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```

Now your string is properly formated, and the `NSURL initWithString` method will work!

Also, just so it is clearer for you in the future, you can take advantage of Objective-C's dot notation syntax when you set your `quoteNumber` string, as follows:

```
NSString *quoteNumber = self.textBox.text;
```

Also, you are trying to pass this quoted number into your `urlString` as a digit (as seen with the `%d`), remember that `quotedNumber` is a NSString object, and will crash when you try to pass it to the `stringWithFormat` method. You must convert the string first to a NSInteger, or NSUInteger.

Please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791470/convert-nsstring-to-nsinteger) to how to do that (don't worry it's very easy)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your string. Try this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%@", quoteNumber];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking of NSString's `stringWithFormat:`:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%@", quoteNumber]]
```

Also note the change to %@ for the format specifier, since it is an instance of NSString (not an int)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
[NSURL initWithString:]
```

requires ONE parameter of NSString type but you passed TWO parameters .

You need to pass a single NSString parameter . Change your code from

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%d", quoteNumber];
```

to

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://TestSite.com/virdirectory/Webservice1/Service1.asmx/GetQuote?number=%d", quoteNumber]];
```